# What is tuples per second? (in cloud computing)

Tags: cloud, data-transfer

What exactly is a tuple here? Is it the familiar data structure? I am learning cloud computing newly, and this term (tuples per second) has been hard to understand. Great if someone could explain it with some background.

Comment: Did you search for this first? This strikes me as something that should be easy to find information on.

Comment: Yes. I searched quite a bit and read a few stackoverflow questions related to this as well. I just didn't find a good enough answer explaining the basics.